# OS on SSD other programs on HDD, performance?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, performance, operating-systems

I want to setup a new PC where in only the OS is installed on SSD. All other programs will be installed on the HDD. I'm doing this to reduce cost since bigger SSDs are more expensive.

My question is, will all the programs not benefit from SSD in terms of performance? And, the only benefit I will have is fast OS boot time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff loaded from SSD will be more responsive. This includes:

- OS boot
- OS utilities (Windows Explorer etc.)
- temporary files
- hibernation file (`hiberfil.sys`)
- pagefile
- program settings and caches (AppData)
- OS updates
- opening documents (unless you move them to the other drive)
- …and more

Stuff loaded from HDD will be less responsive.

- Program start times
- Load times for files stored on other drives

TL;DR: Stuff on system partition will run faster.

Comment: Does this mean that programs installed on HDD but uses AppData (from SSD) will have some benefit in speed?

Comment: Yes. The extent to which you notice that will depend on how much of the program's performance is effected by those files.